# Uploading photo to server to use as profile picture.

Tags: php, html, sql, photo-upload

I have a problem that I'm working with right now. Currently I have a registration form that accepts a few fields from the user and a picture upload field for the profile picture. Currently the profile picture name is being inserted into the database but when viewing the folder of the target location there is no sign of the picture. Right now the page goes white and loads a little tiny broken picture in the top left hand corner. Any advice?

**Profile Page**

```
<?PHP
ob_start();
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors',"On");
session_start();
if (!isset($_SESSION['username'])) {
    header('location:login.php');
}
?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<style>

</style>
<!--[if lt IE 9]>

        <script src="http://html5shim.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script>

    <![endif]-->        

    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script>  $(document).ready(function(){

                $('#login-trigger').click(function(){

                    $(this).next('#login-content').slideToggle();

                    $(this).toggleClass('active');                  



                    if ($(this).hasClass('active')) $(this).find('span').html('&#x25B2;')

                        else $(this).find('span').html('&#x25BC;')

                    })

          });
</script>
</head>

<body>
<header class="cf">

<nav></nav>

</header>
<h1 style="text-align:center"> The Animator - BETA</h1>
<hr />
<div id="nav" style="text-align:center">
<ul style="text-align:center">
<li><a href= "theanimator.html" ><strong>Home</strong></a></li>
<strong><li><a href= "industrial.html" >Industrial</a></li>
<li><a href= "educational.html" >Education</a></li>
<li><a href= "independent.html"  >Independent</a></li>
<li><a href= "emergent.html"  >Emergent</a></li>
<li><a href= "team.html" >Team</a></li>
<li><a href= "project.html"  >Project</a></li>
<li><a href= "budget.html" >Budget</a></li>
<li><a href= "profile.html" >Profile</a></li></strong>
</ul>
</div>
<hr />
<div style="padding-left:19%"><input type="text" value="search" />
<input type="button" value="Search!" name="search"/>
</div>
<h1 style="text-align:center">Profile</h1>
<div style="padding-left:15%; padding-right:15%; font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;">
  <div style="font-size:18px; text-align:center; font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;">
    <p>
      <?php 

    $querytest = "SELECT * FROM account WHERE idaccount = " . $_GET['idaccount'];
    $result = mysql_query($querytest);

    echo $_SESSION['idaccount'];
  ?>
    </p>
    <p>
      <?php

echo $_SESSION['username'];
  ?>
    </p>
  </div>
  <p style="text-align:center;"><?php echo $_SESSION['email'];?></p>
    <div style="font-size:18px; width:100px; text-align:left; margin-left:201px; padding-left:10pt">Specialties</div>
</div>
  <div style="width:100%; float:left;">
  <div style="width:30%">
  <?php
 $db_name = "animator"; // Database name
  $link = mysql_connect('localhost', 'root', 'admin');
if (!$link) {
die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}
//echo 'Connected successfully';
mysql_select_db($db_name) or die("Could not connect to Database" .mysql_error());
  $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM animator.account WHERE idaccount=" . $_SESSION['idaccount'] . ";");
  if (!$result) { // add this check.
    die('Invalid query: ' . mysql_error());
}
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
 header("Content-type: image/jpeg");
     echo mysql_result($result, 0);
} 

   ?>
   </div>
  <div class="previous_work" id="previous_work" style="width:70%; float:left; margin-left:2%;">
  <hr />
  <li>3D Animation</li>
  <li>Scriptwriting</li>
  <li>CGI Animation </li>
</div>
<hr />
  </div>
  &nbsp;
  <hr />
<?php echo $_SESSION['bio']; ?>
</p>
</div>
  </p>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
</div>
<div id="footer"> <hr />
  <p><strong><u><a href="about.html">About The Animator</a> | <a     href="contact.html">Contact</a> | <a href="privacy.html">Privacy Policy</a> | <a     href="faq.html">FAQ</a></u></strong><u> | <strong><a     href="questionnaire.html">Questionnaire</a> |</strong></u> <strong><a     href="reports.html">Admin Reports</a> |</strong></u></p>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

**REGISTER PAGE WITH PHOTO UPLOAD**

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors',"On");
include ('database_connection.php');
$target = "/var/www/profile";

if (isset($_POST['formsubmitted'])) {
    $error = array();//Declare An Array to store any error message  
    if (empty($_POST['name'])) {//if no name has been supplied 
        $error[] = 'Please Enter a name ';//add to array "error"
    } else {
        $name = $_POST['name'];//else assign it a variable
    }

    if (empty($_POST['e-mail'])) {
        $error[] = 'Please Enter your Email ';
    } else {


        if (preg_match("/^([a-zA-Z0-9])+([a-zA-Z0-9\._-])*@([a-zA-Z0-9_-])+([a-zA-Z0-9\._-]+)+$/", $_POST['e-mail'])) {
           //regular expression for email validation
            $Email = $_POST['e-mail'];
        } else {
             $error[] = 'Your EMail Address is invalid  ';
        }


    }


    if (empty($_POST['Password'])) {
        $error[] = 'Please Enter Your Password ';
    } else {
        $Password = $_POST['Password'];
    }


    if (empty($error)) //send to Database if there's no error '

    { // If everything's OK...

        // Make sure the email address is available:
        $query_verify_email = "SELECT * FROM account  WHERE email ='$Email'";
        $result_verify_email = mysqli_query($dbc, $query_verify_email);
        if (!$result_verify_email) {//if the Query Failed ,similar to if($result_verify_email==false)
            echo ' Database Error Occured ';
        }

        if (mysqli_num_rows($result_verify_email) == 0) { // IF no previous user is using this email .


            // Create a unique  activation code:
            $activation = md5(uniqid(rand(), true));
            $target = $target . basename($_FILES['photo']['name']);

//This gets all the other information from the form
            $pic=($_FILES['photo']['name']);
            if(!isset($_FILES['photo'])) {
$error[] = "No photo selected !";
}



            $query_insert_user = "INSERT INTO `account` ( `username`, `passwords`, `email`, `picture`) VALUES ( '$name', '$Password', '$Email ' , '$pic')";


            $result_insert_user = mysqli_query($dbc, $query_insert_user);
            if (!$result_insert_user) {
                echo 'Query Failed ';
            }

            if (mysqli_affected_rows($dbc) == 1) { //If the Insert Query was successfull.


                // Send the email:
                $message = " To activate your account, please click on this link:\n\n";
                $message .= WEBSITE_URL . '/activate.php?email=' . urlencode($Email) . "&key=$activation";
                mail($Email, 'Registration Confirmation', $message, 'From: systemadminstrator@theanimator.com');

                // Flush the buffered output.


                // Finish the page:
                echo '<div class="success">Thank you for
registering! A confirmation email
has been sent to '.$Email.' Please click on the Activation Link to Activate your account </div>';


            } else { // If it did not run OK.
                echo '<div class="errormsgbox">You could not be registered due to a system
error. We apologize for any
inconvenience.</div>';
            }

        } else { // The email address is not available.
            echo '<div class="errormsgbox" >That email
address has already been registered.
</div>';
        }

    } else {//If the "error" array contains error msg , display them



echo '<div class="errormsgbox"> <ol>';
        foreach ($error as $key => $values) {

            echo '  <li>'.$values.'</li>';



        }
        echo '</ol></div>';

    }

    mysqli_close($dbc);//Close the DB Connection

} // End of the main Submit conditional.



?><!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Registration Form</title>





<style type="text/css">
body {
    font-family:"Lucida Grande", "Lucida Sans Unicode", Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size:12px;
}
.registration_form {
    margin:0 auto;
    width:500px;
    padding:14px;
}
label {
    width: 10em;
    float: left;
    margin-right: 0.5em;
    display: block
}
.submit {
    float:right;
}
fieldset {
    background:#EBF4FB none repeat scroll 0 0;
    border:2px solid #B7DDF2;
    width: 500px;
}
legend {
    color: #fff;
    background: #80D3E2;
    border: 1px solid #781351;
    padding: 2px 6px
}
.elements {
    padding:10px;
}
p {
    border-bottom:1px solid #B7DDF2;
    color:#666666;
    font-size:11px;
    margin-bottom:20px;
    padding-bottom:10px;
}
a{
    color:#0099FF;
font-weight:bold;
}

/* Box Style */


 .success, .warning, .errormsgbox, .validation {
    border: 1px solid;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding:10px 5px 10px 50px;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: 10px center;
     font-weight:bold;
     width:450px;

}

.success {

    color: #4F8A10;
    background-color: #DFF2BF;
    background-image:url('images/success.png');
}
.warning {

    color: #9F6000;
    background-color: #FEEFB3;
    background-image: url('images/warning.png');
}
.errormsgbox {

    color: #D8000C;
    background-color: #FFBABA;
    background-image: url('images/error.png');

}
.validation {

    color: #D63301;
    background-color: #FFCCBA;
    background-image: url('images/error.png');
}



</style>

</head>
<body>


<form action="registeraccount.php" method="post" class="registration_form" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  <fieldset>
    <legend>Registration Form </legend>

    <h2 style="text-align:center">Create an account!</h2>
    <p style="text-align:center"> <span>Already a member? <a href="login.php">Log in</a></span> </p>

    <div class="elements">
      <label for="name">Name :</label>
      <input type="text" id="name" name="name" size="25" />
    </div>
    <div class="elements">
      <label for="e-mail">E-mail :</label>
      <input type="text" id="e-mail" name="e-mail" size="25" />
    </div>
    <div class="elements">
      <label for="Password">Password:</label>
      <input type="password" id="Password" name="Password" size="25" />
      <p>
              Photo:
            </p>
            <input type="hidden" name="size" value="350000">
            <input type="file" name="photo"> 
            <p>
      </div>

      <br />

    <div class="submit">
     <input type="hidden" name="formsubmitted" value="TRUE" />
      <input type="submit" value="Register" />

    </div>
  </fieldset>
</form>
<button onclick="window.location='theanimator.html';">Go Back!</button>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: This is obviously a `path` related issue.

Comment: I don't see how this is. I've tried the / as you suggested and still experience the same issue.

Comment: You didn't save the file, http://php.net/manual/en/function.move-uploaded-file.php

Comment: I think your `$target = $target . basename($_FILES['photo']['name']);` is the problem and confusing. You probably have to set to the affect of `$targetfile = $target . basename($_FILES['photo']['name']);` because you already declared the target path.

Comment: It still doesn't explain why the whole page is white and only showing a broken picture.

Comment: @ZachHarvey and `Musa` has a point. Where is your saving function? I see no mention of `move_uploaded_file...`. E.g. `move_uploaded_file($_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name'],$upload_path . $filename)`

Comment: what Musa said. You don't appear to be actually moving the file to a permanent location

Comment: @ZachHarvey Try something like this to replace `$target = $target . basename($_FILES['photo']['name']);` - `$pic = move_uploaded_file($_FILES['photo']['name'],$target . $pic);` or something like that.

Comment: @ZachHarvey You're probably getting a blank page, because of the file not being uploaded and the script figures it hasn't finished its work. Again, you have no function to actually `upload/move` the file anywhere. You're only declaring a `path` for it, that's all.

Comment: Replaced that an now I'm getting the same index error for $pic.

$pic = move_uploaded_file($_FILES['photo']['name'],$target . $pic);

Comment: Try `if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['photo']['tmp_name'],$target . $name))` then, again something like that. I don't know what your form looks like. You should look into the PHP upload manual.

Comment: `Food for thought`. When building such an elaborate script/program, I suggest you build it in (tested) blocks, so that way once you know all your functions/blocks are working, you can then piece them together. `Just saying`. I have my own uploading script which works great. I then build `around it` for any special/added features such as database insertion, emailing etc. It will save you a lot of time and possible frustration/aggravation. Once you have a working uploading function, the rest is `gravy`. ;-) Speaking of `gravy`, it's suppertime, I'm hungry. Keep me posted.

Comment: Fred you were right with the path issue but I'm still experiencing the issue with the white page even after confirming the files are being correctly copied to the destination. After all your talk about food it got me hungry. Will continue after dinner!

Comment: @ZachHarvey One thing I can see is that your `order` by which things get executed, is that you're placing `if(!isset($_FILES['photo'])) {` between upload and database insertion. I suggest you place `if(!isset($_FILES['photo'])) {` above anything else and stop them in their tracks, then if everything `passes`, execute database insertion/email etc. That's probably why you're getting a blank screen. If everything passes, then an echo'ed message should appear. Go over your entire sequences step by step and go over it as if "you" were the end user him/herself. You'll see, something will `click`.

Comment: @ZachHarvey Question: Have you declared this yet? `$pic=$_POST['photo'];` anywhere? How have you determined the incoming photo file? Just declaring `$pic=($_FILES['photo']['name']);` isn't enough and is not doing anything really. `$pic=$_POST['photo'];` should be placed underneath `$target = "/var/www/profile";`.

Comment: Tried both of your suggestions and still nothing.

Comment: @ZachHarvey I tested your code as much as I could without having to go through the entire database creation, and my uploading script worked. I can post the code as a `suggestive` answer, meaning that it probably won't fix any other potential problems, so `downvoting it` is `not` an option. Instructions will be in the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**NOTE: This is a Suggestive answer.**

Remove or comment out this line: `$target = "/var/www/profile";`

and place the code I posted below, underneath your `mail()` function,

or above `$message = "To activate your account...` and give that a try/test.

**PATH NOTE:** in regards to `$upload_path = './uploads/';` in my code, 
this is assuming that you are running your script from the `root` of your server.

You could try `$upload_path = '/var/www/profile/uploads/';` but you will need to keep the trailing slash.

You will also need to delete/comment out `$target = $target . basename($_FILES['photo']['name']);`,
or better yet, use my code in that space instead. You will have to test in which spot it will be work best.

**Here is my (tested) code:**

```
$allowed_filetypes = array('.jpg','.gif','.bmp','.png'); // These will be the types of file that will pass the validation.
$max_filesize = 9999999999; // Maximum filesize in BYTES - SET IN to a low number for small files
$upload_path = './uploads/'; // The place the files will be uploaded to (currently a 'files' directory).

$filename = $_FILES['photo']['name']; // Get the name of the file (including file extension).
$ext = substr($filename, strpos($filename,'.'), strlen($filename)-1); // Get the extension from the filename.

// Check if the filetype is allowed, if not DIE and inform the user.
if(!in_array($ext,$allowed_filetypes))
die('The file you attempted to upload is not allowed.');

// Now check the filesize, if it is too large then DIE and inform the user.
if(filesize($_FILES['photo']['tmp_name']) > $max_filesize)
die('The file you attempted to upload is too large.');

// Check if we can upload to the specified path, if not DIE and inform the user.
if(!is_writable($upload_path))
die('You cannot upload to the specified directory, please CHMOD it to 777.');

// Upload the file to your specified path.
if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['photo']['tmp_name'],$upload_path . $filename))
echo 'Your file upload was successful'; // It worked.
else
echo 'There was an error during the file upload. Please try again.'; // It failed

// rest of your code to be placed below
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your help Fred. I'm giving you the answer because this will work without an issues. I've currently figured out another way to do this which was needed as I need to assign a unique ID to each picture and change the file name before uploading to avoid the possibility of the picture being overwritten. 

Now I'll need to compare the inputted data in the database (The picture unique ID) and pull the appropriate picture for the profile.

Comment: @ZachHarvey Thank you Zach. Funny you should say that about the "Unique ID". I was just helping out someone else on a different matter and told the OP that the image file would need to be renamed to a unique ID, for many reasons, and one being that if some people upload from an iPod Touch, iPhone, the default name being sent is called `image.jpg`. If you have any problem with that, leave me a note, I may have a function for that. Cheers

Comment: @ZachHarvey On a continued note, might I suggest using the server's UNIX timestamp, with a concatenated name of the uploader's orginal filename.

Comment: @ZachHarvey I can add my code that I wrote and use to this day (random number name with extras for renaming incoming files), in my answer. You will need to work it a little to suit your needs. Let me know.

Comment: $pic=($_FILES['photo']['name']);
    if(!isset($_FILES['photo'])) {
    $error[] = "No photo selected !";
}

$imgname = uniqid("img_",true) . ".jpg";

 move_uploaded_file($_FILES["photo"]["tmp_name"], "/var/www/profile/" . $imgname);

This is working quite well actually but thank you. I do have a question about displaying the picture if you want to have a private chat?

Comment: @ZachHarvey if you're here now, invite me in, but I can't stay long.

Comment: @ZachHarvey If I can't make it in the chat room, here's something you can use that you'll have to modify: `echo 'Your file upload was successful, view the file <img src="' . $upload_path . $filename . '" title="Anything you want">';`

Comment: @ZachHarvey My above code to view the image, could be placed underneath `move_uploaded_file(...`. That will show the uploaded image right away. Yet again, you will have to modify it to suit your present script, cheers.

Answer (score 0):

This is not a complete fix but I notice a couple of things

As others have suggested you are not moving the picture to a location you can access. Also:

> while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
>   {
>   header("Content-type: image/jpeg");
>       echo mysql_result($result, 0);
>   }

Seems to be using the header() term after you have sent output to the browser. I do notice that you are using ob_start to buffer your output but don't think this will prevent unexpected results.

In the same block of code you seem to be returning the entire row from the mysql result, not just the .jpg data. I suspect that this is the more likely issue since

> $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM animator.account WHERE idaccount=" . $_SESSION['idaccount'] . ";");

Is returning an array with all of the fields from the database. A quick test of the latter theory would be to replace your query with

> $result = mysql_query("SELECT picture FROM animator.account WHERE idaccount=" . $_SESSION['idaccount'] . ";");

Very interested to hear your results.

Comment: Thanks for your response but even after replacing the line of code with your suggestion I still get a blank page with a broken picture at the top.

Comment: Ok How about you write a simple page with the code to select a picture you know is in the database (are you using phpmyadmin to check the database contents?) and just display the picture. This will help you troubleshoot, even if its a pain.