# Php file upload uppercase extension doesn't work

Tags: php, html, upload

I am having a problem uploading files coming from an HTML form. It works only when the extension is not in uppercase. Uploading .jpg will work, but .JPG will not (even after renaming the file on the system). I am completely baffled, I have set no restriction on file extensions since my website is for very personal use. Here is the html form

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="uploader.php" method="post">
Browse file : <input type="file" name="img"><br>
Nom : <input type="text" name="nom"><br>
Prix : <input type="text" name="prix"><br>
Description: <input type="text" name="descr"><br>
<input type="submit" value="Upload">
</form>
```

Here is my script for uploading.

```
$target_path = "../photos/" . $_FILES['img']['name'];

if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['img']['tmp_name'], $target_path)){
    code here
}
```

I will supply further information if nescessary, thanks for helping!

Comment: your script is HIGHLY dangerous. you are directly using the user-supplied filename, allowing a malicious user to scribble their file ANYWHERE on your server. **DO NOT USE THIS CODE**.

Comment: As I said my website is only for very personal use, so I am not worried about this at all. I'm wondering why uppercase extensions cause an issue.

Comment: Just use the `strtoupper()` function to convert everything to upper case, then use the `strtolower()` to convert everything to lower case; includes the file extension. For example: `$image = strtoupper($image);` **then** `$image = strtolower($image);` should do the trick, even though you shouldn't be using that form.

Comment: Or `$image = $_FILES['image'];` `$image = strtoupper($image);` `$image = strtolower($image);` then rest of code. Something to that affect.

Comment: @Fred I already tried to put everyone to lowercase using strtolower, to no avail.

Comment: @JonathanL You have to first convert all to uppercase, then to lowercase after that. Not just one.

Comment: @Fred I just tried using `strtoupper($_FILES['img']);`
 `strtolower($_FILES['img']);` to no avail.

Comment: @JonathanL You have to first declare the variable `$img = $_FILES['img'];` **then** `$image = strtoupper($img);` `$image = strtolower($img);`

Comment: @JonathanL So, any luck?

Comment: @Fred I am even more baffled now, I tried creating other files with uppercase extensions and they uploaded fine. While some others coming directly from a camera, put into the computer with uppercase extensions refuses to upload, really I am not sure what is wrong

Comment: @JonathanL From my past experiences, when uploading from an iPod Touch (and probably iPhone also), is that the default name of the file being uploaded is called `image.jpg`. That could pose a problem.

Comment: @JonathanL Have a look at some of past my answers related to that problem I was facing. **1)** http://stackoverflow.com/a/17016540/1415724 **2)** http://stackoverflow.com/a/17005748/1415724

Comment: @JonathanL I also made a Pastebin file of a similar snippet I wrote, but you have to be a **"member"** of Pastebin.com to view it. [**See my Pastebin snippet here**](http://pastebin.com/pP8JaqDN)

Answer (score 1):

I believe this issue concerns the file upload size configuration in your particular php.ini file not the case of the file extension. The file upload module should be case insensitive. The default upload size for WAMP, for example, is set at a max file size of 2M. I had the issue of uppercase file extensions not being loaded as well, when I compared the file size of the files with uppercase extensions to those with lowercase, the uppercase were over 2M and the lower under- I don't know if this is a windows thing where case denotes file size. In any case what happens is that the $_FILES assoc array is populated, in the case of a single file upload, with a single key value pair. The key being the name value you set in the form input and the value an associative array concerning aspects of the file upload with the keys: name, type, size, tmp_name, and error. The upload file module gets as far as populating the file name, but when it encounters the size larger than the config setting the rest of the assoc array is not populated. So, the file is not moved into the configured tmp directory, the type is not set, size is not set, however, error is set to 1. Because the file is never uploaded to the tmp directory you can't extract it and move it. The solution, go to your php.ini file do a search for the text "file upload" and check the max file size for uploads and compare this against your test files, edit your php.ini accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

Had the same problem - just lower the case of the target path

```
$target_path =  $target_dir . strtolower(basename($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]));
```